# SharePoint 2013 Content Query Web Part 4 Filter

Tags: sharepoint-2013, cqwp

I have the following Code-Snippet to Filter Blogposts in a Content Query WebPart. We need more than the 3 Filters already given in Sharepoint, so I tried it with CMAL-Query.
But the filter´s don´t apply when I add the WebPart to my SP-Page. Any Suggestions how to Change the code?

The Posts should be filtered by Category.

```
 <property name="QueryOverride" type="string">
                <![CDATA[
                <where>
                    <or>
                        <or>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='PostCategory' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>test4</Value>
                            </Eq>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='PostCategory' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>test5</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </or>
                        <or>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='PostCategory' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>Ideen</Value>
                            </Eq>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='PostCategory' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>Meinungen</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </or>
                    </or>
                </where>
            ]]>
            </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

NVM.

I found my mistake. Using the U2U Caml Builder everything now works as expected.